# Outlier detection for time series

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, knn

I wanted to generate a very simple example of anomaly detection for time series. So I created sample data with one very obvious outlier but I didn't get any method to detect the outlier reliably so far. I tried local outlier factor, isolation forests and k nearest neighbors. From what I read, at least one of those methods should be suitable. I also tried tweaking the parameters but that didn't really help.

What mistake do I make here? Are the methods not appropriate?

Below is a code example.

Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)

t=np.linspace(0,10,101).reshape(-1,1)
y_test=0.5+t+t**2+2*np.random.randn(len(t),1)

y_test[10]=y_test[10]*7

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t,y_test)
plt.show;

from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor

clf=LocalOutlierFactor(contamination='auto')
pred=clf.fit_predict(y_test)

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(t[pred==1],y_test[pred==1],'bx')
plt.plot(t[pred==-1],y_test[pred==-1],'ro')
plt.show

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

clf=IsolationForest(behaviour='new',contamination='auto')
pred=clf.fit_predict(y_test)

plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(t[pred==1],y_test[pred==1],'bx')
plt.plot(t[pred==-1],y_test[pred==-1],'ro')
plt.show

from pyod.models.knn import KNN

clf = KNN()
clf.fit(y_test)
pred=clf.predict(y_test)

plt.figure(4)
plt.plot(t[pred==0],y_test[pred==0],'bx')
plt.plot(t[pred==1],y_test[pred==1],'ro')
plt.show
```

Comment: Might be better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com as it's more of an algorithm question than a code error IMO, although it's good to provide a code example

Comment: That's true, I will try it there. Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: Strange, they said the opposite. Your code runs, so if it's an algorithm question maybe edit the question on Stats to clarify?

Comment: I just saw it. I added a plot for clarification, maybe now they'll accept. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Might be too late for a response, but **Hampel filter** might be a simple solution for not too big datasets. [link] (https://www.sktime.org/en/latest/api_reference/auto_generated/sktime.transformations.series.outlier_detection.HampelFilter.html?highlight=hampel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is because of two reasons:

- these algorithms are not designed to handle 1-d data specifically
- they are not designed for ts problem...

you may need to use time series tool for it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you recommend a suitable tool for time series, which is preferably easy?

Comment: @MarcusWenzel maybe some tools mentioned here: https://github.com/yzhao062/anomaly-detection-resources#32-time-series-outlier-detection

Comment: Great resource that you have there, helped me a lot, thanks!